# Training status stuck in "RUNNING" after many hours

Tags: google-prediction

I've launched a training using a CSV of 126 Mo stored in Google Cloud Storage, the CSV has a simple structure ("int","text"). After 8 hours the status is still "Running. Is it normal that the training takes all this time? should I give it a bit more time?

Regards

PS: I've used the Google's APIs Explorer to train the model using the version 1.6 of Prediction API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,
It can take a lot of time.

Go to bed, it should be done by tomorrow :-)